# Using protocol/delegate for changing UITableViewCell from another class

Tags: uitableview, delegates, uitextview

Well, I'm really stuck with the following problem now:

I have 2 classes: NoticeViewAddController (let's call it vc1) and NoticeViewAddControllerAddNotice (let's call it vc2).

vc1 calls vc2. In vc2 there's a UITextView where the user can add some text and hit save (the save button saves it to Core Data, but that's not the point).
When I want to pop vc2 and reveal vc1 again, I want its UITableViewCell get the text from vc2's UITextView (reloading the UITableView is also required, isn't it?).

From what I've read so far, delegetation and a protocol seem to be the most elegant way, but I really don't get it.

1. Does vc1 have to have that protocol?
2. Which method should be in that protocol?
3. How can I then change the cell.textLabel.text for indexPath.section == 0 and indexPath.row == 0).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think a protocol would be too much in that case. Just stick with implementing a delegate by setting an ivar & property in vc2 :

```
@class vc1;

interface vc2 {
    vc1* delegate
...
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) vc1* delegate;
```

Define it as assign and then you don't need to memory-manage it.
In vc1, set the delegate before calling vc2 :

```
[vc2_instance setDelegate:self];
```

In vc1 you need a callback method for notifying the result :

```
- (void) notify:(NSString* thetext);
```

The notify method is the ideal place to reload the table view.
You then call it in vc2 just before popping it out :

```
[delegate notify:textlabel.text];
```

Hop this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy if you are using a NSFetchedResultsController for your table view. With that, you can implement the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate Protocol methods in your vc1 view controller:

```
– controllerWillChangeContent:
– controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:
– controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:
– controllerDidChangeContent:
```

This way, when you save changes to your managedObjectContext in the vc2 viewcontroller, the `hasChanges` event is automatically generated, notifying the fetchedResultsController, and the fetchedResultsController executes these delegate methods. Your table will automatically get updated with the change, using code in your delegate methods. In your case, I think your focus is on the `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` method where the change type is `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate`.

If it's an update type, you can just configure the cell at `indexPath` the same way you do it in the tableView protocol method `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. Of course, in this case the cell is already in the table, so you aren't inserting it, but you are re-configuring it.

You will bracket your delegate methods with 1controllerWillChangeContent:`and 1controllerDidChangeContent:` containing calls to `[tableView beginUpdates];` and `[tableView endUpdates]` respectively (where `tableView` is changed to a reference to your tableView object). These keep the fetchedResultsController and the tableView happy while the changes are being done, and you don't get any errors about them being out of sync. (This is probably not a big problem if you're only changing the content of a cell.)

I'll dig up an example for you when I get back to my office and post it here. I did this over the weekend on a project I am working with and it resolved a lot of problems.